# Lambda expression returning a HelperResult and MvcHtmlString

Tags: c#, lambda, html-helper

I'm creating a menu control where I need to specify the Html element and inside this Html use `Html.ActionLink(...`

The markup I want to create should look like this, `<li><a href="/some-link"></a>Some name</li>`

My menu control has the following signature today `(this Htmlhelper html, Func<IPage, MvcHtmlString> content)` and I'm using this menu control like this `@Html.Menu(page => Html.ActionLink(page)` where `Html.ActionLink(IPage)` is my own extension method.

So how should the signature look if I would like to write something like this to create my menu item: `@Html.Menu(page => @<li> @Html.ActionLink(page) </li>)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had some kinda brain freeze or something, but here is the solution I chose

```
public static MvcHtmlString Menu(this HtmlHelper html, Func<IPage, Func<object, HelperResult>> itemContent) {}
```

I this is how I use it in my project

```
@Html.Menu(page => @<li>@Html.ActionLink(page)</li>)
```